# Транспонировать матрицу 5x2 в 2x5

Tags: java

Изучаю матрицы, транспортировать 2х2 разобралась, а вот 5x2 в 2x5 не могу.
Как транспортировать матрицу  5x2 в 2x5 ?

```
0 1    --->  0 2 4 6 8  
2 3          1 3 5 7 9
4 5
6 7
8 9
```

```
public class transpose1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[][] array = {
                {2,3},
                {4,5},
        };
        System.out.println("Оригинальная матрица");
        System.out.println("------");
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            for (int j = i+1; j < 2; j++) {
                int temp = array[i][j];
                array[i][j] = array[j][i];
                array[j][i] = temp;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Новая матрица");
        System.out.println("------");
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: покажите попытки решения задачи

Comment: добавила 2на2 , но 5х2 в 2х5 не знаю даже с чего начать

Comment: Это же из онлайн курса, там все ведь расписано

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение этой задачи заключается в инвертированном присваивании значений в двойном цикле:

```
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
        newMatrix[j][i] = matrix[i][j];
    }
}
```

Значения новой матрицы заполняются значениями из старой матрицы. Содержимое ячейки `[i][j]` записывается в ячейку `[j][i]`. Вот и вся суть.

Answer (score 1):

К слову алгоритмы для матриц уже придуманы и собраны в [commons-math3](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-math3)

Например транспонирование:

```
double[][] matrix = {
        {0, 1},
        {2, 3},
        {4, 5},
        {6, 7},
        {8, 9}
};

System.out.println(MatrixUtils.createRealMatrix(matrix).transpose());

>>>> Array2DRowRealMatrix{{0.0,2.0,4.0,6.0,8.0},{1.0,3.0,5.0,7.0,9.0}}
```

Answer (score -3):

что-то вроде этого?

```
class transpose11 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] result = new int[2][5];
        int[][] array = {
                {0,1},
                {2,3},
                {4,5},
                {6,7},
                {8,9},
        };
        System.out.println("Оригинальная матрица");
        System.out.println("------");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < result[i].length; j++) {
                result[i][j] = array[j][i];
            }
        }
 System.out.println("Новая матрица");
        System.out.println("------");
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < result[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(result[i][j] + " ");

            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Да что-то вроде этого. Только не пишите комментарии как ответ.

Comment: В этом ответе тот же код, что и в вопросе, только неправильный код транспонирования заменён на правильный код, [приведенный в ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1247020/199822) @Zhenyria.